# Downloading app with firebase dynamic link and deleting and re-downloading returns a value in the link

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

1 : I click on a dynamic link which I have created with data in it(firsntname, lastname etc..) and go to the appstore.
2 : I build the app on Xcode to simulate a download with the dynamic link
3 : The app is being downloaded and in the openURL a dynamic link with value is returned
4 : Now I delete the app and rebuild the app without clicking on the dynamic link
5 : There is still a dynamic link found with data in it... How is that possible? I deleted the app so everything should be deleted right? Is it because how I simulate it?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47998881/2546685

Link will be returned during one hour, but confidence level will vary. By checking confidence level you can use link only once.