# Tapping on a firebase dynamic link is remembered for a while, how to delete it?

Tags: ios, firebase, url, hyperlink, firebase-dynamic-links

I have created a firebase dynamic link with data in it(username, email etc..). When I click on the link the I am being redirected to the appstore. From there I download the app and when the app is openend for the first-time I extract the data from the dynamic link url in the "in the openURL" method. I use that data to create an account.

When I delete the app and redownload the app, I still get the same dynamic link with the same data in it. I don't want that to happen. Is it possible to delete the firebase dynamic link afther using it once?

Hope someone can help me out with this one. There is no information about this anywhere...

Comment: I am also facing the same issue in the React-Native using https://rnfirebase.io/dynamic-links/usage in iOS. Have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Is this duplicated question?

Anyway, check out this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47998881/2546685

Also keep in mid, that fingerprint based matching may be not enough when you passing sensitive information in the link. You may want to have "unique" confidence for such links. Firebase Dynamic Links provides "copy unique match" that is uniquely matched and privacy aware matching technique.